# declare: -A: invalid option

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm getting this error `declare: -A: invalid option` while declaring the following map

```
declare -A ApiResourcePath_LambdaFunc_Map=( \
    [signup]="CreateUser" \
    [verify-user]="VerifyUser" \
    [login]="Login" \
    [change-password]="ChangePassword" \
    [forgot-password]="LostPassword" \
    [reset-password]="ResetPassword" \
    [refresh-token]="RefreshToken" \
)
```

I didn't find any syntax error here. Why I am getting this error ?

Comment: What OS are you on?  What is the output of `bash --version`?

Comment: See also:[Bash 4 associative arrays: error “declare: -A: invalid option”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047648/bash-4-associative-arrays-error-declare-a-invalid-option).

Comment: @John1024 Thanks John, you are absolutely right. I was running bash version 3 in macOS. bash 4 supports the above script but bash 3 doesn't.

Comment: This may also be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111397/associative-arrays-in-shell-scripts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Support for associative arrays was added to `bash` in version 4.0-alpha.  For whatever reasons, macOS is still using `bash` 3.2.  If you want to use associative arrays on macOS, one option is to install a modern `bash` using, for example, [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

For more on this and the work-around options for macOS users, see [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047648/bash-4-associative-arrays-error-declare-a-invalid-option).

Comment: The reason macOS is still using version 3.2 is because bash 4 is licensed under GPLv3, which Apple cannot use. For more -https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx