# get an error typeset: not found when i launch my script by crontab?

Tags: shell-script, cron, error-handling, typeset

I use this portion of code to set default values in my config on my script.sh

```
# Copyright (c) 2015 
# Licence MIT ( http://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/ ).
#!/bin/sh

typeset -A config # init array
config=( # set default values in config array
    # chemin du dossier de log
    [log]=$SCRIPTPATH"/logs"
    # chemin du dossier local 
    [local]=""
)
```

when i launch my script with shell console everything is OK and working
But if I want to schedule launch with crontab i get an error

```
/var/********/script.sh: 148: /var/********/script.sh: typeset: not found
/var/********/script.sh: 149: /var/********/script.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

here is my crontab line

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

* * * * * root /var/********/script.sh -c file.conf > /dev/null 2> /var/********/errors.log
```

can you explain me why ? thanks

Comment: How is your cron job invoking the script? Does the script have a she-bang line?

Comment: sorry, i've updated the post

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't know what is she-bang line... I'm a noob on shell scripting

Comment: Is that the entire script? Or is the first line something like `#!/bin/sh`   ?

Comment: no, the script lines are only a small portion concerned by the error (typeset ...)
and the crontab has some lines befor my cron call (for cron daily reports or system things i guess)

Comment: my script.sh start with

Comment: # Copyright (c) 2015 
# Licence MIT ( http://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/ ).
#!/bin/sh

Answer (score 2):

Your script is assuming that it's running under a shell that supports arrays, such as bash or ksh. The lack of a she-bang line means that cron (by default) would invoke /bin/sh to execute the script. Specifically setting `SHELL=/bin/sh` in the crontab enforces this behavior.

If you're using bash interactively, specify bash as the she-bang line -- the first line must be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

not the second line or subsequent lines.

Alternatively, specifically invoke bash in the cron job, either by setting:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

or with:

```
* * * * * root bash /var/********/script.sh -c file.conf > /dev/null 2> /var/********/errors.log
```

Comment: For more on which shells support this, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150015/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111397/ .

Comment: it seems I do not have /usr/bin/bash on my server. I use your last example and it seems to work perfectly. thank you very very very much !

Comment: root@**:~# type bash
bash is hashed (/bin/bash)

Comment: @J.D use whatcha got :)

Comment: @J.D Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.